# EC2 instance reboot stucked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reboot

I was changing an EBS settings and need to reboot my EC2 instance.

I did it via AWS Console, Instance -> Reboot

After more than 30 minutes, still my application is not working and in Status Check I see: 1/2 checks passed

My application is using by hundreds of users, how long it takes to finish a reboot?

Here are my last Instance Logs:

```
[[0;32m OK [0m Unmounted /run/user/1000.
[[0;32m OK [0m Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped target Swap.
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors…ng dmeventd or progress polling...
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[[0;32m OK [0m Reached target Shutdown.
[[0;32m OK [0m Reached target Final Step.
Starting Reboot...
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,…sing dmeventd or progress polling.
Stopping LVM2 metadata daemon...
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
http://8432758.683718 reboot: Restarting system
```

Comment: instead of waiting for reboot you can perform `stop` and then `start` instance action.

Comment: but then i will lost my data on this instance... is there any option to take it back?

Comment: Are you using instance store?

Comment: only data in RAM will lost no in the hard drive

Comment: Ok, i stopped an instance and started it and still i have "Instance reachability check failed at July 17, 2020 at 3:09:00 AM UTC+2 (11 minutes ago)".

How can I fix it guys? :( :( :(

I'm using EBS store

And this time there are no instance logs :(

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/system-reachability-check/

Comment: I dont know how to start, i just wanted to reboot an instance and everything failed. I cant even read logs of EC2 because its empty log :/

Comment: thats might be because of EBS changes

Comment: Somehow EBS got crashed, even mounting it in new instance still fails. I lost a lot of data and I've no idea how to recover it...